# the repellant effect of religion

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "the repellant effect of religion" mean "the effect produced by religion that (the effect) is impervious to reasons"?

> As it’s said, “success has many fathers,” and so it is with getting our fellow Americans to see the light of reason. We can credit our existential security; our educational, scientific, and technological advancement; the shift in family size and the role of women in society; and **the repellant effect of religion** as handmaid to reactionary politics. But to my mind, not enough attention has been paid to the impact made by the writers of new atheism: Dawkins, Dennett, Harris, Hirsi Ali, and Hitchens.

> [Source](https://secularhumanism.org/2020/12/give-the-four-horsemen-and-ayaan-their-due-they-changed-america/):  Give The Four Horsemen (And Ayaan) Their Due. They Changed America.

Comment: Note the use of semicolons. The constituent being addressed is not _the repellent effect of religion_, but rather _the repellent effect of [religion as handmaid to reactionary politics]. That is, the effect of religion's being used by reactionary politicians has been that many people are repelled by both the politicians and the religions that have allied with them.

Answer (score 1):

The writer is talking about two phenomena, and the effect that the first has on the second.

The first, in the writer's view, is the effect that religion has in repelling (rather than attracting) people (possibly because of the behaviour of some religious leaders, although this is not stated).

People, the writer feels, react negatively to religion; they reject its teachings. And for this reason, by implication, they reject the religious impulse to civil obedience and respect for authority.

This attitude leads them to embrace extreme political views, whether left-wing or right-wing, that are in stark contrast to the conventional politics of the day.

Answer (score 1):

The test is saying that several things have helped "our fellow Americans to see the light of reason". (I suppose that the author previously indicted what s/he considers to be "the light of reason.") One of these things was "the repellant effect of religion as handmaid to reactionary politics". That is, by using religious argument to support "reactionary politics", the writer thinks people will dislike religion by association with those political views, and tus be more open to "reason" which the writer seems to see as opposed to, or at least significantly different from religion.